# posting string in for loop with comma separator volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

I have an API which accepts parameters in String form with comma separator and I need to paas the params from arraylist using android volley.The Log shows its being posted correctly using comma separator with the only the 1st element of the loop is getting posted.
The code i like this

```
     @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("user_id", String.valueOf(Common.UID));
        for(int m=0;m<Common.Category.size();m++)
        {
            if(Common.Category.size()>1) {
                if (m < Common.Category.size() - 1) {
                    Log.e("Posting Category params",Common.Category.get(m) + ",");
                    params.put("cat_id", Common.Category.get(m) + ",");
                } else {
                    Log.e("Posting cat last params", Common.Category.get(m));
                    params.put("cat_id", Common.Category.get(m));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("only 1 Cat params", Common.Category.get(m));
                params.put("cat_id", Common.Category.get(m));
            }
        }
        for(int n=0;n<Common.langRemoveHash.size();n++) {
            if (Common.langRemoveHash.size() > 1) {
                {
                    if (n <Common.langRemoveHash.size() - 1) {
                        Log.e("Posting LangId params",Common.langRemoveHash.get(n) + ",");
                        params.put("lang_id", Common.langRemoveHash.get(n) + ",");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Posting Last LangId ",Common.langRemoveHash.get(n));
                        params.put("lang_id", Common.langRemoveHash.get(n));
                    }
                }
            }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("Posting Only 1 Lang Id ",Common.langRemoveHash.get(n));
                    params.put("lang_id", Common.langRemoveHash.get(n));
                }

        }
        for(int p=0;p<subCatArraySize;p++)
        {
            if (p>1) {
                if (p<3) {
                    Log.e("Posting subCatId params", "5" + ",");
                    params.put("sub_cat_id", "5" + ",");
                } else {
                    Log.e("Posting last subcatId", "15");
                    params.put("sub_cat_id", "15");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("Posting only 1 subcatId", "15");
                params.put("sub_cat_id", "15");
            }
        }
        //params.put("password","123");
        //int j=0;
        //for(String object: langId){
            //params.put("languageID["+(j++)+"]", object);
            // you first send both data with same param name as friendnr[] ....  now send with params friendnr[0],friendnr[1] ..and so on
        //}
        return params;
    }

};
```

THE LOGCAT shows proper parsing

```
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/
E/Posting Category params: 1,
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/        E/Posting cat last params: 3
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/z     E/Posting LangId params: 3,
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/    E/Posting LangId params: 11,
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/E/Posting Last LangId: 4
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/E/Posting only 1 subcatId: 15
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/E/Posting only 1 subcatId: 15
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/E/Posting subCatId params: 5,
04-21 12:04:12.943 23485-25015/E/Posting last subcatId: 15
```

Comment: post example of which type of request or string you want to generate

Comment: I am fetching the data selected by user  and it has to go in simple string form like cat_id: 1,3 sub_cat id:2,3,4,user id:235,lang_id,2,3.suppose if user selects lang id 1 and 3 it is being added to langRemoveHash arraylist which is shown above and I need to paas that array in string form in api

Comment: take a arraylist of string and add value what you want to pass and then use arraylist.toString() to convert into string :)

Comment: I already have arrays for all the values fetched ie..langRemoveHash and Category both of which I am fetching from the class Common.can u give u a short example of code how to do that

Comment: see my answer here . Hope it will helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and check its helpful for you or not

```
JSONArray listCatId = new JSONArray();
for (int m = 0; m < Common.Category.size(); m++) {
            if (Common.Category.size() > 1) {
                if (m < Common.Category.size() - 1) {
                    Log.e("Posting Category params", Common.Category.get(m) + ",");
                    listCatId.put(Common.Category.get(m));
//                  params.put("cat_id", Common.Category.get(m) + ",");

                } else {
                    Log.e("Posting cat last params", Common.Category.get(m));
                    params.put("cat_id", Common.Category.get(m));
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("only 1 Cat params", Common.Category.get(m));
                params.put("cat_id", Common.Category.get(m));
            }
        }
        params.put("cat_id",listCatId.toString() );
```

Comment: this is the response I got from the api.need to get rid of the array brackets and the double quotes                                                   
  :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '["4","3"])' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`language`) WHERE `id` IN (["4","3"])

Filename: /home1/doitteco/public_html/audio_buzz_admin/models/admin_model.php

Line Number: 201

Comment: use replace function to remove brackets

Comment: i used params.put("cat_id",listCatId.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","")); and it replaced the brackets along with the rest of the items as well after the comma

Comment: not working.leave it I have asked to make changes in the API instead.thanks for your help:)

Comment: great solution payal :)